# How can I get the real argument list from a frozen sys.argv call using freeze_support?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pyinstaller, command-line-arguments, argv

I have a unique problem - my solution, which I wish to package using pyinstaller, JITs some things based on sys.argv at startup. When you use `multiprocessing` with `freeze_support` on Windows, multiprocessing needs to pass in different arguments to initialize the new process. The original sys.argv are eventually set when the target function is invoked. How can I get the original sys.argv before invocation of the target function?

```
import sys
import multiprocessing
print('ArgV:', sys.argv)


def print_argv():
    print(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    print_argv()
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=print_argv)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

When packaged with pyinstaller and run with `--hello=True`, yields:

```
ArgV: ['scratch.exe', '--hello=True']
['scratch.exe', '--hello=True']
ArgV: ['scratch.exe', '--multiprocessing-fork', 'parent_pid=16096', 'pipe_handle=380']
['scratch.exe', '--hello=True']
```

I would like some magic code that gives me my original `sys.argv`, that is, `--hello=True`, when `sys.argv` is set to `--multiprocessing-fork...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never extensively played with freezing executables, but I have several ideas...

Taking a look at `multiprocessing.spawn._main()`, copying across the original `sys.argv` happens here:

```
preparation_data = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
prepare(preparation_data)
```

If you override `Process.__new__`, you should be able to run code before `_bootstrap` (which eventually calls `run` on the process object), but after `sys.argv` is received.

```py
import sys
import multiprocessing
print('ArgV:', sys.argv)

def print_argv():
    print(sys.argv)
    
class myProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if __name__ == "__mp_main__":
            print("hook", sys.argv)
        instance = super(myProcess, cls).__new__(cls) 
        instance.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        return instance

if __name__ == '__main__':
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    print_argv()
    p = myProcess(target=print_argv)
    p.start()
    p.join()
```

Another idea is to hook the unpickle process by overriding `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`.

```py
class myProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    
    def __getstate__(self):
        return self.__dict__.copy()
    
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        print("hook", sys.argv)
        self.__dict__.update(state)
```

Finally you could hook the audit event generated when pickle looks for a custom class to unpickle:

```py
class myProcess(multiprocessing.Process):
    pass

def hook(event_name, args):
    if "pickle.find_class" in event_name:
        if args[1] == myProcess.__name__:
            print("hook", sys.argv)
        
sys.addaudithook(hook)
```

All of these occur roughly at the same time during loading of the new process, and I couldn't say which is the most robust...

Comment: ofc all of this seems a little silly when you could just rewrite the target function as well, which is about to be executed, but it's a little fun to break stuff sometimes to see how it works.